# Console: How to check if a protocol is accessible

Tags: console, protocols

I am trying to find a method of checking if a protocol works on a computer. For example smtp/ftp. I guess I would have to check this somehow in console, right? My question is non-OS-specific, so I would like to know how to do it universally or in major systems Linux/Windows/OS X.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smpt ftp http are protocols that are in the application layer of the osi layer.
So the OS does not have anything to do with these protocols. If you install an Ftp client like fileZilla you can connect to a ftp server. fileZilla speaks then the ftp protocol with the server.
you can also install an ftp server and configure it. So that other clients can connect with your server and speak the protocol together.
if you just want to find out whether a remote server is running a specific service (ftp, smtp...) you can use a port knocker or check it with telnet.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model